# Triple Integral Inequality

Tags: inequality

> If $0<a\leq b$, $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, $z\in[0,1]$, and $f$ is an integrable decreasing convex function$$\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_a^b\int\limits_a^bf\left(2\sqrt{xy}\right)dxdydz\leq\int\limits_a^b\int\limits_a^b\left(zf(x)+(1-z)f(y)\right)dxdy$$

My attempt:
Change the order of  integral and take the integral with respect to z and use AM GM and defintion of convexity. I do not know how to use the fact that the function is decreasing helps.
Propose by Dan  Sitaru- Romanian Math Magazine

Comment: What does the above inequality mean? The integrand in Left hand side does not depend upon $z$. So the integral with respect to $z$ in LHS can br dropped. But your right hand side depends on $z.$ Do you want to integrate the RHS with respect to $z$? Or you mean, the inequality holds for any fixed $z$?

Comment: I think we want to show it holds for any z

Comment: please make sure you've got the question written out exactly. AM-GM: $f$ decreasing means you would get $f(2\sqrt{xy})\geq f(x+y)$.

Comment: + I KNOW THIS WE ARE LOOKING FOR OPPOSITE

Comment: You may eliminate $z$ on both sides.

Comment: Your L.H.S. is essentially equal to $\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(x)dx.$ On the other hand, the L.H.S. does not even make sense. Imagine what happens when $x=y=b$ for example, you will run through $f(2b)$ while $f$ is only defined on $[a, b].$ There is something missing in the inequality, as it stands right now it is meaningless.